# Working around possible Kendo UI and Wijmo SpreadJS compatibility issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, kendo-ui, wijmo

I think I may be hitting a compatibility issue using Kendo UI and SpreadJS together.  If I include JQuery, Kendo and SpreadJS references in an HTML page, then Chrome gives me the error "Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" in the dev console.  IE also hits the same error (stack overflow).

I'd be really grateful if anyone has any ideas on either what I'm doing wrong, or how I can get these libraries to play nicely with each other!

Cheers,
Scottie

**Page Source:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.wijmo.com/spreadjs/jquery.wijmo.wijspread.all.3.20142.12.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.1.319/js/kendo.all.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cydq1rao/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't analyzed the cause, but it will work if you change the order in which you include the libraries (Kendo UI first, then SpreadJS)